# Split serial monitor output to only save part of the output

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, bluetooth, c, gsm

This is the output i get from the serial monitor from using a HM10 in . How could i go about splitting the data using arduino uno.  I only want to save the last 12 digits before the :- (4CAA0DE091B7) for it to then be in a format to send as an SMS using a GSM module

```
OK+Set:1OK+Set:1OK+RESETOK+DISISOK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4CAA0DE091B7:-062OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:38F9D379C9E5:-062OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:446B17218E0C:-073OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:649BDE9A25C5:-077OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:DF12A8020D32:-042OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4AAC2B4B1C7C:-081OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:7F4B515BC186:-079OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:42AB41C03534:-059OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:7D2A86B2A8CD:-082
OK+DISCEOK+DISISOK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:38F9D379C9E5:-063OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:42AB41C03534:-063OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4CAA0DE091B7:-062OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4AAC2B4B1C7C:-073OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:446B17218E0C:-071OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:7F4B515BC186:-079OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:649BDE9A25C5:-089OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:0CF98919DB7C:-077OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:DF12A8020D32:-041OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:56
OK+DISISOK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:00000OK+DISISOK+DISCEOK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4AAC2B4B1C7C:-071OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:38F9D379C9E5:-080OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:7F4B515BC186:-081OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4CAA0DE091B7:-063OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:0CF98919DB7C:-077OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:446B17218E0C:-070OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:649BDE9A25C5:-077OK+DISC:000
OK+DISCEOK+DISISOK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4AAC2B4B1C7C:-075OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4CAA0DE091B7:-076OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:38F9D379C9E5:-063OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:649BDE9A25C5:-078OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:DF12A8020D32:-044OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:42AB41C03534:-059OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:446B17218E0C:-071OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:7D2A86B2A8CD:
```

Answer (score 1):

implement a circular buffer of say 30 characters.

clear the circular buffer

read into the circular buffer, char by char

when the last 13 characters in the buffer are: `:4CAA0DE091B7` Then the prior 12 characters are the data of interest